# In iOs, is it possible to programmatically stop my app from being auto updated from AppStore?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

Like question states, can I in my application set a parameter that stops the application from being auto updated from AppStore when a new version is available?

I know I can turn auto update on/off in general, by going to Settings on iPad/iPhone, but I wondered if I could stop just my app from being auto updated.

Thankful for all help :)

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Maybe its better to release brand new app?

Comment: The distribution of the server side application is desentralized, so it would be advantageous for the user to better control when the app is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that using the iOS application. Apple does not allow it.